# Using CMake in Embarcadero

Tags: cmake, c++builder, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am trying to get CMake to work with Embarcadero 10.2.3 (Tokyo). I see a some help and blogs. I looks fine (I haven't tried so far), but I get confused about the existing cbproj file that I have. I get the impression that I need a CMake file list (CMakeLists.txt) as well as a cbproj file, if I need to build from the IDE. So in that case, any time I need to add files or settings I need to do in both. Is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: [Looks like it, yes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_CMake_with_C%2B%2B_Builder).  I see nothing in the documentation that implies CMake can compile a `.cbproj` file.  So, you will need a `.cbproj` file when compiling with the IDE or MSBuild, and a separate `CMakeLists.txt` file when compiling with CMake.

Comment: There is also a tutorial, might help: https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/david-millington-c-product-manager/entry/using-cmake-with-the-free-embarcadero-c-compiler

Comment: @RemyLebeau I wasn't expecting CMake to compile a `.cbproj`. I was looking to see if there is any tool that embarcadero has which will do this conversion to `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Thanks @usr1234567. This and other blogs is what I am going thru.

Comment: @MathewJoy no tool that I am aware of